# Multithreading Application won't run after JUnit Test

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea, junit

I'm having problems with my Printer-Counter School Problem. It's supposed to be a multithreading application and runs fine so far. But when I running it the second or third time it won't work anymore.. No error message. Looks like Threads sleep forever or so. Also when I test it with a JUnit test it won't work. But sometimes it does... which is already strange itself.

```
public class CounterPrinter {


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.out.println("Usage: CounterPrinter <min> <max>");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    Storage s = new Storage();
    Printer d = new Printer(s, Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    Counter z = new Counter(s, Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

    z.start();
    d.start();

    z.join();
    d.join();


    Thread.sleep(5000);

}

}



public class Printerextends Thread {
private Storage storage;
private Integer ende;


Printer(Storage s, Integer ende) {
    this.storage = s;
    this.ende = ende;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    while (storage.hasValue()) {
        try {

            System.out.print(speicher.getValue(ende) + " ");
            Thread.sleep(50);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

}

public class Counter extends Thread {
private Storage speicher;
private int max, min;

Counter(Storages, int min, int max) {
    this.storage = s;
    this.max = max;
    this.min = min;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        try {
            storage.setValue(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

}


public class Storage implements StorageIf {
private Integer wert;
private boolean hasValue = false;

@Override
public synchronized Integer getValue(Integer ende) throws InterruptedException {
    if(wert.equals(ende)){
        hasValue = false;
        return wert;
    }else {
        while (!hasValue()) {
            wait();
        }

        hasValue = false;
        notifyAll();
        return wert;
    }
}


@Override
public synchronized void setValue(Integer wert) throws InterruptedException {
    while (hasValue()){
        wait();
    }
    hasValue = true;
    this.wert = wert;
    notifyAll();

}


@Override
public boolean hasValue() {
    return hasValue;
}
}
```

Hope someone can spot a mistake I made

Thanks a lot!

Comment: With debugging try hitting the "pause" button and see where you threads have ended up by examining their stack traces...

Comment: If something multithreaded sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, you can bet your house it will be a synchronization issue.

Comment: what is this multi-threaded application supposed to do?

Comment: So the Counter class is supposed to increase a value from 1 to 50 and storing it after every increment in the Storage Object. The Printer Class is supposed to get the Storage value and print every number individually. When debbuging I see my main Thread on WAIT sometimes... Dont know how to figure out the synchronization problem :(

Comment: Storage boolean hasValue is not volatile and the Storage hasValue( ) method is not synchronized.  So when Printer calls hasValue( ) on it's storage object, it may not see the current value of hasValue and thus may cause the thread to apparently hang.

Comment: Worked 2 times but not a third time. Changed the hasValue Boolean to volatile and its getter method to synchronized.

Comment: Seems like if I put a little delay between starting both Threads in the main Method it works all the time :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you conflate 2 states :

- there is currently a value available
- there will be no more values

Add an `hasEnded()` method to your Storage class, checking if the end value has been reached. Make sure to synchronize this method, as well as the `hasValue()` method. Synchronization needs to be done on both read and write access!

Then make `Printer`'s while loop check `hasEnded`, rather than `hasValue`.

Finally : get rid of all the `sleep()` calls.

Your own answer, solving the problem with sleep, is not a real solution. A thread safe program does not depend on a computer's performance to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    z.start();
    z.sleep(100);
    d.start();
```

Putting a delay between starting the tow Threads solved the problem for me. My Computer was probably too fast down the road in Thread z before it even started Thread d. Thats why it hung itself up in 50% of the time.

Thanks to everyone tho :)